# Infinite recursion due to unintended template argument type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, c++17

Please consider the following `boost::math::pdf`-like implementation of a generic probability density function evaluation:

```
template<typename T, class Distribution>
inline typename Distribution::result_type pdf(Distribution const& d, T const& x) {
    return pdf(d, static_cast<typename Distribution::result_type>(x));
}

template<typename RealType>
RealType pdf(std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType> const& d, RealType const& x)
{
    if (d.a() <= x && x <= d.b())
        return 1 / (d.b() - d.a());
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to define another `pdf` function which takes a distribution and a vector and evaluates the probability density of each vector component. The function should be invokable for nested vectors as well. I've tried something like this:

```
template<typename T, class Distribution>
inline typename Distribution::result_type pdf(Distribution const& d, std::vector<T> const& x)
{
    return std::reduce(x.begin(), x.end(), typename Distribution::result_type{ 1 },
        [&](auto const& p, auto const& x) { return p * pdf(d, x); });
}
```

Example code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> x = { {1}, {2, 3}, {4} };
std::vector<double> y = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::uniform_real_distribution<> d;
std::cout << pdf(d, x) << std::endl;
std::cout << pdf(d, y) << std::endl;
```

This works as it should be. However, if I change `std::uniform_real_distribution<> d;` to `std::uniform_real_distribution<float> d;`, then I end up in an infinite recursion for the call of `pdf(d, x)` (for obvious reasons). So, how do I need to change the code? Maybe such that it works for other containers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two overloads for the first case (which basically do the same thing):

```
template<typename T, class Distribution>
inline typename Distribution::result_type pdf(Distribution const& d, T const& x) {
    return pdf(d, static_cast<typename Distribution::result_type>(x));
}

template<typename RealType>
RealType pdf(std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType> const& d, RealType const& x)
{
    if (d.a() <= x && x <= d.b())
        return 1 / (d.b() - d.a());
    return 0;
}
```

collapse them into one:

```
template <typename R, typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, R>, int> = 0>
auto pdf(std::uniform_real_distribution<R> const& d, T x) -> R
{
    if (d.a() <= x && x <= d.b()) {
        return 1 / (d.b() - d.a());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or simpler to just block type deduction on the 2nd argument entirely (`std::type_identity` is C++20 but is trivial to implement):

```
template <typename R>
auto pdf(std::uniform_real_distribution<R> const& d, std::type_identity_t<R> x) -> R
```

Comment: (a) Why did you remove the reference from `x` (and didn't wrote `std::type_identity_t<R> const&`)? (b) Is there a reason why you're using a trailing return type (instead of `template<typename R> R pdf(std::uniform_real_distribution<R> const& d, std::type_identity_t<R> const& x)`)? (c) Regarding collapsing the first case: I've clearly have many other `Distribution`'s I want to specialize `pdf` for, but I guess there is no benefit in introducing the generic forward declaration as I did, right?

Comment: (d) I'm not sure if you noticed it, but your solution solves the problem with the vector overload as well. Do you see an easy way to extend it such that it works for `std::list`'s and other containers as well?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: (a): we generally pass arithmetic types by value (b) style? (c) it seems no benefit (d) You might SFINAE if `T` is a "container" of type convertible to `R`.